# Use cookie to get id, perform inner join on matching fields

Tags: php, sql, cookies, inner-join

This is my first post, but I have found this forum to be very useful! I hope you can help me.

My conundrum is this: I have users log on and then rate each other. Once a user logs in, I want them to be able to see the ratings they made (this one I got working - the reviews I can select by a unique id generated by a form) and also see a summary of the ratings that they have received. This is where it seems to get tricky. I tried an inner join but it didn't produce any results.

Right now I have this part up above my html

```
<?php 
    include "connect.php";
    if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site'])) 
    { 
        $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
        $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site']; 
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))   
        { 
            //if the cookie has the wrong password, they are taken to the login page 
            if ($pass != $info['password']) 
            {
                header(""); 
            } 
            //otherwise they are shown the admin area    
            else 
            {
                echo ""; 
                echo ""; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
     else 
    //if the cookie does not exist, they are taken to the login screen 
    {            
        header(""); 
    } 
include "settings.php";
?>
```

And this part after my html

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT r.user, r.rating1, r.rating2, r.rating3, u.username
                             FROM reviews r INNER JOIN users u ON r.user=u.username
                            WHERE r.user='$userid' ORDER BY r.user DESC") 
                or die(mysql_error()); 

        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>View Comments</th>
                  <th>Rating 1</th>
                  <th>Rating 2</th>
                  <th>Rating 3</th>
              </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo '<td><a href="showit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">View/Print</a></td>';
               echo '<td>' . $row['rating1'] . '</td>';
               echo '<td>' . $row['rating2'] . '</td>';
               echo '<td>' . $row['rating3'] . '</td>';
               echo "</tr>"; 
        } 
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Unfortunately, I don't get any results at all, though I see about 20 ratings for this person in the sql table.

It's also throwing a "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in reviews.php on line 19" error.

There's probably a stupid mistake in there, but I'm getting codeblind and frustrated.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is line 19:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo '<td><a href="showit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">View/Print</a></td>';
               echo '<td>' . $row['rating1'] . '</td>';
               echo '<td>' . $row['rating2'] . '</td>';
               echo '<td>' . $row['rating3'] . '</td>';
               echo "</tr>"; 
        }
```

you should use the position of the values inside the array like 1,2,3 .. and so on , not ratings1 ,ratings2 .. and so on.

Comment: Thanks Johny! I'm still working with this to see if I can figure it out. :)

Comment: I ended up abandoning the join and updating the ratings table from the cookie at the thank-you page, then just calling the iterations from the review table. Thanks for your response, Johny. I'm calling you the correct answerer.